# How to pass objects within objects between activities with parcelable

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parcelable

Im pretty new in Android Studio.

I'm trying to pass an ArrayList from one activity to another using parcelable. Within the class Recipe I declare another ArrayList which I cannot get a hold of when starting the other activity.

**Recipe.java:**

```
public class Recipe implements Parcelable {
    String name;
    ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredients;

    public Recipe(String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    protected Recipe(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Recipe> CREATOR = new Creator<Recipe>() {
        @Override
        public Recipe createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Recipe(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Recipe[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Recipe[size];
        }
    };

    public void addIngredients(String[] amountList, String[] ingredientList, String[] unitList) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ingredientList.length; i++) {
            ingredients.add(new Ingredient(ingredientList[i], Double.parseDouble(amountList[i]), unitList[i]));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(name);
    }
}
```

**Ingredient.java:**

```
public class Ingredient implements Parcelable {
    private String ingrdnt;
    private double amount;
    private String unit;
    private String cat;
    private boolean checkedItem;

    public Ingredient(String ingrdnt, double amount, String unit) {
        this.ingrdnt = ingrdnt;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.unit = unit;
        //this.cat = category;
        this.checkedItem = false;
    }

    protected Ingredient(Parcel in) {
        ingrdnt = in.readString();
        amount = in.readDouble();
        unit = in.readString();
        cat = in.readString();
        checkedItem = in.readByte() != 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<Ingredient> CREATOR = new Creator<Ingredient>() {
        @Override
        public Ingredient createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Ingredient(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Ingredient[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Ingredient[size];
        }
    };

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(ingrdnt);
        parcel.writeDouble(amount);
        parcel.writeString(unit);
        parcel.writeString(cat);
        parcel.writeByte((byte) (checkedItem ? 1 : 0));
    }
}
```

**In main:**

```
private ArrayList<Recipe> recipes = new ArrayList<>();
//recipes obviously holds a bunch of recipes so it's not empty.
intent.putExtra("recipes", recipes);
System.out.println(recipes.get(0).ingredients.get(0).getAmount());
```

> System.out: 2.0

**In second activity:**

```
recipes = this.getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("recipes");
//Same print as above
System.out.println(recipes.get(0).ingredients.get(0).getAmount());
```

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference

**Have I implemented the parcelable in a wrong way or why can I not get a hold of the Ingredient objects?**

*I've read about other ways to pass objects between activities but it seems like parcelable might be the best way to do it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you basically forgot to write the ingredients of the `Recipe` to the output `Parcel` which is given to the `Recipe.writeToParcel` method.

You can write the `ArrayList<Parcelable>` with [`writeTypedList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel#writeTypedList(java.util.List%3CT%3E)) and read it back with [`readTypedList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel#readTypedList(java.util.List%3CT%3E,%20android.os.Parcelable.Creator%3CT%3E)).

So your `Recipe` constructor which accepts a `Parcel` should be like:

```
protected Recipe(Parcel in) {
    name = in.readString();
    ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
    in.readTypedList(ingredients, Ingredient.CREATOR);
}
```

while your `writeToParcel` of the `Recipe` should become:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(name);
    parcel.writeTypedList(ingredients);
}
```

The `NullPointerException` you are seeing is caused by the fact that you do not allocate a new `ArrayList` in the constructor of `Recipe` which accepts a `Parcel`, so when you call `recipes.get(0).ingredients.get(0).getAmount()` in the second `Activity` the `ingredients` `ArrayList` is `null`, thus the `Exception`.

Also note (but not related to the problem) that there exist a [`writeBoolean`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel#writeBoolean(boolean)) and a [`readBoolean`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel#readBoolean()) with which you can write and read values of type `boolean` (I am saying this for the `Ingredient` class implementation).

Try those out and let us know if it worked properly.

Comment: Thank you very much!! It worked fine :) Are you referring to the checkedItem variable or do you mean that I should use it to implement ingredients from the beginning?

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped. I am refering to `checkedItem` indeed.